# IE Developer Tool: do I have the network view?

Tags: internet-explorer

I need to see the loaded resources of my webpage from IE8 Developer Tool (to be clear: the equivalent of the tab "Net" in Firebug).

But I cannot find it. Does it exist ?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look into the [fiddler debugging proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), it's invaluable. It will tell you which resources IE has loaded, let you "replay" form submissions and so on. It's true that IE hasn't got a resources tab à la firebug, or webkit, but this isn't so far off.

Comment: On a side note, the IE9 preview does include this functionality in the developer tools.